# Oracle Remove Duplicate Combination of Three

Tags: sql, oracle, select, duplicates, sql-order-by

I have a view that returns 3 columns with 3 hashes.
The third column is sometimes null.

These combinations repeat in different orders, for example:

```
1,2,3
1,3,2
2,1,3
2,3,1
3,1,2
3,2,1
```

I think it's 6 rows per 3 joined hashes.

These hashes are actually IDs for the same file (but this isn't relevant right now).

**

I have tried various things and seem to have found a suitable solution - but I am wondering if there is an even better way.
Also please note that sometimes one of the 6 rows maybe is missing.

I'm currently trying the following and it seems to be working:

```
select one, two, three from DUPLICATE_DOCUMENTS_3JOINS
where (three is null and two<one) or (three<two AND two<one);
```

Any thoughts about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want one row, then the simplest option that comes to mind is a row-limiting query:

```
select d.*
from duplicate_documents_3joins d
order by one, two, three
fetch first row only
```

In Oracle 11g and earlier, you can use `row_number()` instead:

```
select one, two, three
from (
    select d.*, row_number() over(order by one, two, three) rn
    from duplicate_documents_3joins d
) d
where rn = 1
```

Comment: It's whining about SQL command not properly ended. Probably something minor.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you running? The `fetch` syntax was added in 12c.

Comment: Shoot, 11 something. It's fine  though, answer is relevant for others.

Comment: @Menios: I updated my answer with an equivalent solution for earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a distinct select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LEAST(one, two, three) AS one,
    CASE WHEN one > two AND one < three
         THEN one
         WHEN LEAST(one, two, three) = one AND two < three
         THEN two
         ELSE three END AS two,
    GREATEST(one, two, three) AS three
FROM yourTable;
```

Given the six records in your sample data set, which are the six permutations of 1, 2, and 3, the above query would just return a single record 1, 2, 3.  The above logic should work for any set of one, two, three values (in any order).

Answer (score 1):

If you have three joins, fix the problem in the *join*s:

```
select . . .
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on . . . and t1.one < t2.two join
     t t3
     on . . . and t2.two < t3.three
```

If might be a little more complicated if you have to deal with `left join`s, but the idea would be similar.